# how to pass variable value to urllib in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, urllib

How do I pass the value of variable `a` the below url after token:

```
   a = 123
   import urllib
   testfile = urllib.URLopener()
   testfile.retrieve("'https://test.test.com/comp/export?format=csv& 'token:' ,"data.csv")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.format`

**Ex:**

```
a=123
import urllib
testfile = urllib.URLopener()
testfile.retrieve("https://test.test.com/comp/export?format=csv&token:{0}".format(a),"data.csv")
```

**Demo:**

```
a = 123
print("https://test.test.com/comp/export?format=csv&token:{0}".format(a))
https://test.test.com/comp/export?format=csv&token:123
```

Comment: value is coming as {0} not 123

Comment: I have added a demo in the ans.

Comment: if token: is coming in multiple places, then format(a) should be given in all places or only at last

Comment: This should help [link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/format)

Comment: value is passing when using print command. but failing inside testfile.retrieve